# Detect a method for local variable from DMP file

Tags: c#, .net, dump

I have a process dump, but do not have PDB files for the particular build.
Looking into managed memory I see a bunch of object like this:
[image]

What I want to do, is to detect a method (or methods) which these local variables belong.
How to do this without symbol files?

P.S. I can build the same version from sources and get PDBs. But, when I'm trying to browse and select PDB, I'm getting this message:
[image]

Maybe, there's an option to force using my PDBs in Visual Studio?

Comment: afaik, its [not trivially possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64223720/how-to-debug-crashdump-without-having-dependency-to-symbol-files) - especially if it built for release. need a lot of decompiling experience. but i want to know too if its can be done. i always keep pdb around for time of need.

Comment: @BagusTesa, you're totally right about pdbs. But... And yes, this is release build. I'm thinking about rebuilding the same version and installing it with pdbs, but first I want to make sure that it's the only reasonable way (from the point of time resources).